# Why DOM is not updating after updating Data set in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working in angular 2. what i am facing that, i am calling a function of child component from parent. and child function update my data set which initially load html. but when i am standing on same html and call again that function, its shows in console that data set has been loaded with new data but does not load its html.
**Full scenario:** 
i have a search bar in my header section. from where redirects to result page and also call its function which shows query data. but when i already once searched query and standing on result page. new data query will call the function again and data set will be updated. but component dose not reload html according to that data set. how can i reload it?
any suggestions.?
here is code samples.
my **header.ts**

```
Search(){
localStorage.setItem('val',JSON.stringify(this.query));

this.router.navigate(['/results']);
this.mobiles.ngOnInit();

      }


}
```

and **resuls.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {


      this.query=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('val'));
alert(this.query)

 this.httpService.searchGeneric(this.query,1).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.Getspecs = data;

    this.count=data['totalItems'];

    this.ref.detectChanges();
      this.ref.reattach();  

    console.log(data)

     }
    );
```

why new changes are not appearing in html of result component? have anyone any idea about this? needed any help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you re-routing to the same page again once you call the function on the result page. If you are on a component and you reload the same component again, Angular is not going to refresh your binding. Its rather a performance improvement to not refresh the binding again for a already loaded component.

Comment: Read [https://angular.io/guide/router#observable-params-and-component-reuse] This will show you the way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way Angular works.

You are using the same function which means you are re-routing to the same component again.

If you are on a component and you reload the same component again, Angular is not going to refresh your binding. Its rather a performance improvement to not refresh the binding again for a already loaded component.

However, angular does provide a way around in case you need to explicitly change bindings on reload. You can use `params` observable and subscribe to the `params` on a route change. Any action within this subscription will force to change the binding.

More information [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#observable-params-and-component-reuse) at Angular official docs.

Comment: any simple example? or any modifications which you may can provide in my code?